# How to make a specific Column Uneditable In datagridview?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Using a DataGridView, how can I make a specific column uneditable while the grid view itself has "Allow editing" enabled?

Also, how can I execute an event when the selected index in a ComboBox in the DataGridView has changed? Here, ComboBox is a column type.

Another question is, how can I make the header title aligned to the center? I can't find the appropriate property.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've got a few questions here.

> (1) How can I make a specific column uneditable in DataGridView?

Set the [`ReadOnly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.readonly.aspx) flag on the particular column you want to make uneditable.

```
dataGridView.Columns["YourColumnName"].ReadOnly = true;
```

> (2) How can I execute an event when the selected index on a ComboBox in the DataGridView changes?

If it's in your DataGridView, it's not a ComboBox; it's a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Unlike the ComboBox control, the DataGridViewComboBoxCell does not have SelectedIndex and SelectedValue properties. Instead, selecting a value from a drop-down list sets the cell Value property.

This one I'm not familiar with, as I've never tried it myself. It appears you want to subscribe to the [`EditingControlShowing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing.aspx) event and then see if [something like this](http://generally.wordpress.com/2007/12/07/datagridview-get-selectedindex-of-datagridviewcomboboxcolumn/) works for you (with a little tweaking).

> (3) How can I make the header title align in the center?

Set the [HeaderCell.Style.Alignment](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vblanguage/thread/df6d6a35-f61e-43c8-8cd5-a691529bb486)

```
dataGridView.Columns["YourColumnName"].HeaderCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
```