# Unable to make DataGridView Columns readonly

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, readonly

I am making an application where the user can enter and exit and "edit" state on different items.  When entering the edit state, I want to enable certain columns on a DataGridView and when they exit, disable them. The code below is run when the Boolean `EditMode` changes.

```
'Change ReadOnly to Not EditMode
'dgv.ReadOnly = Not EditMode                           'Works
dgv.Columns("colCode").ReadOnly = Not EditMode         'Does not work
dgv.Columns("colText").ReadOnly = Not EditMode         'Does not work
dgv.Columns("colTarget").ReadOnly = Not EditMode       'Does not work
dgv.Columns("colCheck").ReadOnly = Not EditMode        'Does not work
```

When changing the entire DataGridView ReadOnly property, the grid becomes editable/not editable like I would expect it too, but I only want to enable 4/6 columns.  The column names are correct, and the logic is the same, but enabling the columns individually is not changing the ReadOnly property and I am not able to edit the columns.  Stepping through the debugger, when entering edit mode I can see `dgv.Columns("colCode").ReadOnly = Not EditMode` evaluate to `dgv.Columns("colCode").ReadOnly = False` but stepping past, the ReadOnly property remains true...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `dgv.ReadOnly = true` then the columns are all forced to be `ReadOnly = True`.
So set `dgv.ReadOnly = False` and set the ReadOnly property only on the columns to true.

Comment: So the grid property overrides the individual column property? Good thing to know.

Answer (score 1):

**Refer this**  - [How to make a specific Column Uneditable In datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11282729/how-to-make-a-specific-column-uneditable-in-datagridview)

You will find different details about setting the column read only.

You can make a column read only before binding the data:

```
this.dgrid.Columns("colName").ReadOnly = true
```

If you need to do for individual cells within the column, then you will have to loop and set them like this:

```
this.dgridvwMain.Rows(index).Cells("colName").ReadOnly = true
```

Then another way is to handle the CellBeginEdit event and set e.Cancel = True when you need disable the cell.

```
Private Sub DataGridView_CellBeginEdit(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewMsg.CellBeginEdit
    If DataGridViewMsg.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells("disable").Value = "Y" Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

**References:**
[How to: Make Columns Read-Only in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cze614bb(v=vs.110).aspx)
[DataGridViewColumn.ReadOnly Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can set ReadOnly Property at three levels. You can make entire dataGridView or entire column or entire row as ReadOnly .

```
dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;

dataGridView1.Rows[index].ReadOnly = true;

dataGridView1.Columns[index].ReadOnly = true;
```

> **Note:** [DataGridView.ReadOnly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.readonly(v=vs.110).aspx) property override the column or cell's ReadOnly property. First set the it to false and then change
>   for specific column or cell.